# DB2 need help for alter table alter column set data type

Tags: sql, db2

I need to change the data type of column from `VARCHAR` to `DECIMAL`

I have data in the column, but they are all numeric values like `10.00, 25.50` etc,

Now when I do `alter table MY_TABLE alter column COL1 set data type to decimal(11,2)` its failing.

Whats the process i can follow here.

I'm sure this is not a new question but i couldn't find the solution, so instead of raking my brains i'm asking out here.

Comment: What's the error it's returning?  (I understand that it's most likely a 'field-incompatability' issue, but it's best to state that explicitly - especially for history).

Comment: It appears that the datatypes aren't compatabile - `VARCHAR` can't be switched to a `DECIMAL` type.  Additionally, the `TO` after the `DATA TYPE` clause is unnecessary, and may give parser errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The syntax is 
`ALTER TABLE {tableName} MODIFY {Column-Name} {New-Column-Definition}`
I.E. `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE MODIFY COL1 DECIMAL(11,2)`</strike>

Generally this (altering the column data type) won't convert the existing data to the new type and will probably set the incompatible values as NULL (or it may make a smart conversion it's pretty much DBMS server specific)

You can do something like this if the data volume is not too high

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD COLUMN Temporary decimal(11,2);
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET Temporary=CAST(COL1 AS DECIMAL(11,2));
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP COLUMN COL1;
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE  CHANGE Temporary COL1 decimal(11,2);
```

Edit: The first part is probably incorrect

Comment: Given the information in the question, this is what I have done in the past, and would probably do again. Though it does assume no triggers etc on the existing column.

Comment: @apokryfos - In DB2 (for both major versions), `MODIFY` is _not_ used - it's `ALTER COLUMN`

Comment: ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP COLUMN COL1;-this command is not working getting error like :SQL0952] Processing of the SQL statement ended.  Reason code 10. Cause . . . . . :   The SQL operation was ended before normal completion

Comment: This worked for me except that I had to add the RESTRICT keyword to the end of the DROP COLUMN statement, run a reorg, and then use ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME COLUMN Temporary TO COL1; instead of the final statement here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming DB2 won't allow you to provide a guide for the data conversion but I pray to the SQL Server gods.

Given that assumption, add a new column, migrate the data over, verify your work, drop the original column, rename the new.

- `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD col1_new decimal(11,2) NULL`
- `UPDATE MY_TABLE SET col1_new = CAST(col1 AS decimal(11,2)`
- Check counts of distinct values, nulls etc between `col1` and `col1_new` bearing in mind `10.00`, `10.0` and `10` would be different values in `varchar` and one value in `decimal`. It does not sound like that is an issue in your data but something to look for if the counts differ
- `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE DROP COLUMN col1`
- I have no idea what the db2 equivalent of `sp_rename` is

Comment: Does it have to be add column -> load values -> delete old column -> rename new column, can this not be simplified?

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the system tables under "SYSTOOLS" schema. Then try changing it again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @apokryfos solution, it works fine! 
It's not complete though, some SQL commands fails with error 
**SQLCODE: -668, SQLSTATE: 57016**

Example:

`SELECT count(COLUMN)
        FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
        WHERE id = ID_NUMBER
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY`

This will fail!

To solve this, you need to REORG the table. Open the DB2 Shell, and type the following commands:

> ```
> db2 connect to <your database name here>
> db2 REORG TABLE SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME
> ```

There is also an SQL command to REORG, I didn't try it though:

> ```
> CALL SYSPROC.ADMIN_CMD('REORG TABLE SCHEMA.TABLENAME');
> ```

**Reference:**
[Failing update table in db2 with SQLCODE: -668, SQLSTATE: 57016, SQLERRMC: 7;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396046/failing-update-table-in-db2-with-sqlcode-668-sqlstate-57016-sqlerrmc-7)