# In DB2 unable to alter column due to sqlcode=-668

Tags: db2-luw

I have been getting the -668 error trying to expand a column from 8 octets to 20 octets. I got the -668 error which when I looked it up at ibm.com I got

```
"-668 THE COLUMN CANNOT BE ADDED TO THE TABLE BECAUSE THE TABLE HAS AN EDIT PROCEDURE DEFINED WITH ROW ATTRIBUTE SENSITIVITY"
```

So reading about an edit procedure, I see:

```
An edit procedure receives the entire row of a base table in internal Db2 format. It can transform the row when it is stored by an INSERT or UPDATE SQL statement or by the LOAD utility. An edit procedure can be defined as WITH ROW ATTRIBUTES or WITHOUT ROW ATTRIBUTES in a CREATE TABLE statement.
```

I did the reorg statement mentioned at
[Failing update table in db2 with SQLCODE: -668, SQLSTATE: 57016, SQLERRMC: 7;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396046/failing-update-table-in-db2-with-sqlcode-668-sqlstate-57016-sqlerrmc-7/20402891)

and then I could alter the table as I wished. However, the REORG seems to be more for defragging or somehow optimizing the table, but it does not say anything about removing an edit procedure. Could someone explain how there's an edit procedure, and further it has row sensitivity, yet there's no triggers, procedures in the schema that I can see. When I generated the DDL for the table, I didn't see anything suggesting an edit procedure.

Comment: [SQL0668N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic3.html#sql0668n) error has multiple reason codes. Please, provide exact SQL statement you run and **exact** message you get on this statement.

Comment: BTW, there is no analogue of DB2 for Z/OS [Edit procedures](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/admin/src/tpc/db2z_editroutine.html) in Db2 for LUW.